# do ajax request as return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so i got this setInterval inside a success method in jquery ajax request. i want when downtime == 0, it will return the whole ajax request. but when it is happen, it keep requesting to the API until meet such condition. anyone know why? thanks for any help! you can check it out in https://jsfiddle.net/83f2wLup/3/

```
setInterval(() => {
                downtime -= 1
                if (downtime <= -1) {
                    return doAjaxReqiest
                }
                next.innerText = "Next question in " + downtime
            }, 1000);
```

Comment: you want to close the setInrval when 0 is hit?

Comment: Be aware that `setInterval` is not guaranteed to actually run after specified amout of milliseconds. Browser can even delay/pause execution if you switch tabs.

Comment: You need to `clearInterval`, or use `setTimeout` to continue

Comment: As @freedomn-m has mentioned, I think your use case needs `setTimeout` as you only want it to happen once after a set amount of time where as `setInterval` does the action at intervals of set time repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

```
          const interval = setInterval(() => {
                downtime -= 1
                if (downtime <= -1) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    return doAjaxReqiest;
                }
                next.innerText = "Next question in " + downtime;
            }, 1000);
```